# Add key to multiple Python dictionaries within list during for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key

I have a python list that is compromised of multiple dictionaries within a list.

```
{"timestamp":"2019-10-05T00:07:50Z","icao_address":"AACAA5","latitude":39.71273649,"longitude":-41.79022217,"altitude_baro":"37000","speed":567,"heading":77,"source":"FM89","collection_type":"satellite","vertical_rate":"0","ingestion_time":"2019-10-05T02:49:47Z"}
{"timestamp":"2019-10-05T00:11:00Z","icao_address":"C03CF1","latitude":48.12194824,"longitude":-44.94451904,"altitude_baro":"36000","speed":565,"heading":73,"source":"FM89","collection_type":"satellite","vertical_rate":"0","ingestion_time":"2019-10-05T02:49:47Z"}
{"timestamp":"2019-10-05T00:11:15Z","icao_address":"A0F4F6","latitude":48.82104492,"longitude":-34.43157489,"altitude_baro":"35000","source":"FM89","collection_type":"satellite","ingestion_time":"2019-10-05T02:49:47Z"}
```

I am trying to add the key **minute** for all of the dictionaries within the list, and don't care for it's value at the moment, and run into a runtime error, which after reading on the reasoning is expected.

```
{"timestamp":"2019-10-05T00:11:15Z","icao_address":"A0F4F6","latitude":48.82104492,"longitude":-34.43157489,"altitude_baro":"35000","source":"FM89","collection_type":"satellite","ingestion_time":"2019-10-05T02:49:47Z", **"minute": "test"**}
{"timestamp":"2019-10-05T00:11:15Z","icao_address":"A0F4F5","latitude":48.82104492,"longitude":-34.43157489,"altitude_baro":"35000","source":"FM89","collection_type":"land","ingestion_time":"2019-10-05T02:49:47Z", **"minute": "test"**}
```

```
for data in list:
     for value in data:
         if value == 'latitude' or value == 'longitude':
             data[value] = float('%.2f'%(data[value]))
```

```
what are possible ways to add keys to a dictionary while on a loop.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the standard dictionary assignment syntax in a loop to add a new key/value pair to each dictionary in your list:

```
>>> x = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]
>>> for data in x:
...     data['minute'] = 'test'
...
>>> x
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'minute': 'test'}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'minute': 'test'}]
```

You can read more about dictionaries in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).